# Join three MySQL tables so that I don't get repeating data

Tags: mysql, xml

I have three mysql table `tblOne`, `tblTwo` and `tblThree`

```
SELECT tblOne.bookID AS bookID,
  tblOne.title AS title,
  tblOne.author AS author,
  tblOne.blurb AS blurb,
  tblOne.isbn AS isbn,
  tblOne.coverImage As coverImage,
  CONCAT_WS(" ", tblThree.firstName, tblThree.lastName) AS fullName,
  tblTwo.rating,
  tblTwo.reviewText AS review,
  CONCAT_WS(" ", tblTwo.reviewDate, tblTwo.reviewTime) AS reviewDate
FROM tblTwo
INNER JOIN tblOne
  ON tblTwo.bookID = tblOne.bookID
INNER JOIN tblThree
  ON tblTwo.userID = tblThree.userID
WHERE tblTwo.bookID = 1000102;
```

The output populates an XML file, for this book, there are two reviews and as such the data for `title`, `author` etc is pulled twice. How can I overcome this as when I try to access the tag from within a `JavaScript` query, it fails as it says it is undefined. I think that this is due to having more than one result.

The above SQL actually does work, my PHP was erroneous, however...

How can I return the book details even when there is no `review`? Currently, only books that have been reviewed get their details returned.

Comment: How do you edit the sql in the question? Is there a tag to do so?

Comment: If you are getting more than one result it means that one user submitted more than one review for the same text, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are using INNER JOIN, which requires rows to exist in joined table. Use LEFT JOIN instead, which returns rows from the first-listed table even if rows from the left-joined table don't exist:

```
SELECT tblBooks.bookID AS bookID,
    tblBooks.title AS title,
    tblBooks.author AS author,
    tblBooks.blurb AS blurb,
    tblBooks.isbn AS isbn,
    tblBooks.coverImage As coverImage,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', tblMembers.firstName, tblMembers.lastName) AS fullName,
    IFNULL(tblReviews.rating, '0'),
    tblReviews.reviewText AS review,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', tblReviews.reviewDate, tblReviews.reviewTime) AS reviewDate
FROM tblBooks 
LEFT JOIN tblReviews
    ON tblReviews.bookID = tblBooks.bookID
LEFT JOIN tblMembers
    ON tblReviews.userID = tblMembers.userID
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8;
```

Notice that I've listed `tblOne` *first* in the FROM clause, which is necessary to get all books even if some have no reviews.

You'll have to deal with `null` values when there are no reviews. Consider using `IFNULL()` to generate blanks or a default value, eg

```
IFNULL(tblTwo.rating, '') -- instead of just tblTwo.rating
```

Or

```
IFNULL(tblTwo.reviewText, 'None') -- instead of just tblTwo.reviewText
```

etc

Comment: `tblTwo` is the review table, so this will only pull data if there is a review...

Comment: Where does the `IF` go? and will it still return the book details?

Comment: You use IFNULL() instead of simple column values. See edit to answer. And yes, the query will return books without reviews. I suggest you copy-paste it and execute it and see what happens. I have edited the answer since first posting it, so please reread it.

Comment: There is no error but the code doesn't return the book details.

Comment: Your edit ruined by query - you removed the LEFT joins and put the INNER joins back, AND you changed the table order! You basically just pasted in your query with the correct table names. I have repaired the query. Please be more careful when editing answer. Try it now.

Comment: The query still doesn't produce any results. Is the `WHERE` clause at the bottom causing no results as the `bookID` wont be in the `tblReviews` table. Will rearranging the `JOINS` help?

Comment: Thank you so so much, this would have taken me forever!

Comment: I've just checked and now, it will only yield one result even if there are more than one reviews...

Comment: the SQL only yields one result

Comment: The bookID is pulled dynamically, see here for a working example, http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/modules/ci227sem2v7/ when you click on a book, the bookID is passed to a php script that returns an xml file that contains the book details and associated reviews.

Comment: Please explain in detail why you expect more than one row if book id is in the where clause. Did you know that CONCAT_WS joins up all review rows into one big concatenated column, so you only get one row per book? Since you used that function in your original question, I assumed that's what you wanted, but maybe I'm wrong. Please edit your question if necessary to show sample data and expected output if you need it to clarify your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

SQL will always form the cartesian product between the tables meaning that if you have one book with 2 reviews and each review has 3 tags, you will have 6 rows returned to cover all of the data combinations.

You cannot have one book per row if you are joining on a table where the number of expected elements per join is greater than 1. You will need to restructure the XML logic (not sure how you go from SQL -> XML) to cluster taking the redundancies into account.

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP_CONCAT and join the table/table_three results.  Try something like:

```
SELECT tblOne.bookID AS bookID,
    tblOne.title AS title,
    tblOne.author AS author,
    tblOne.blurb AS blurb,
    tblOne.isbn AS isbn,
    tblOne.coverImage As coverImage,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
                (SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", tblThree.firstName, tblThree.lastName) 
                           AS fullName,
                       tblTwo.rating,
                       tblTwo.reviewText AS review,
                       CONCAT_WS(" ", tblTwo.reviewDate, tblTwo.reviewTime) 
                           AS reviewDate
                FROM tblTwo     INNER JOIN 
                     tblOne ON tblTwo.bookID = tblOne.bookID
                                INNER JOIN 
                     tblThree ON tblTwo.userID = tblThree.userID
                     WHERE tblTwo.bookID = 1000102) 
                SEPARATOR ' '
                )
FROM tblTwo     INNER JOIN 
     tblOne ON tblTwo.bookID = tblOne.bookID
                INNER JOIN 
     tblThree ON tblTwo.userID = tblThree.userID
WHERE tblTwo.bookID = 1000102;
```

Comment: there is an error in this, I think it is on the GROUP_CONCAT line

Comment: Sorry I was trying to get it to print out the mysql error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', tblMembers.firstName, tblMembers.lastName) 
              ' at line 8

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 18 - "WHERE tblReviews.bookID = 1000102)"